Hibernate 6.5.2 per entity ID generation
I have mnigrated to hibernate 6.5.2 and realised that
@GenericGenerator has become deprecated.
Most of my entites have abstract superclass called IdentifiedEntity, with ID field and generator which uses sequence of name {entity_name}_sequence and alocationSize = 1 which is 50 by default. I needed  @GenericGenerator for that behavior, where I can specify both options(and sequence suffix and allocationSize) and it was only in my superclass as follows:
How can I accomplish that? I mean generation settings only in superclass with entity sequence suffix and allocationSize = 1. We have @SequenceGenerator annotation but it doesn't allow us to specify sequence suffix and requires full sequence name which means that it is suitable only in specific entity class, not in superclass. If it's not possible in new hibernate is it a good or bad practice to move general ID generation settings to superclass instead of specifying in concrete entity class? Thanks in advance
